# Name of input and output tensors when loading Keras model to TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use Keras' model in "pure" TensorFlow (I want to use it in Android app). I've successfully exported Keras model to protobuf and imported it to Tensorflow. However running tensorflow model requires providing input and output tensors' names and I don't know how to find them. My model looks like this:

```
seq = Sequential()
seq.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(3, 15, 15), name="Conv1"))
....
seq.add(Activation('softmax', name="Act4"))
seq.compile()
```

When I'm printing tensors in TensorFlow I can find:

```
Tensor("Conv1_W/initial_value:0", shape=(32, 3, 3, 3), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Conv1_W:0", dtype=float32_ref)
Tensor("Conv1_W/Assign:0", shape=(32, 3, 3, 3), dtype=float32_ref)
Tensor("Conv1_W/read:0", dtype=float32)

Tensor("Act4_sample_weights:0", dtype=float32)
Tensor("Act4_target:0", dtype=float32)
```

Hovewer, there are no tensors that have shape (3,15,15).

I've seen [here](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) that I can add "my_input_tensor" as input, hovewer I don't know which type is it - I've tried TensorFlow's and Keras' placeholders and they gave me this error:

```
/XXXXXXXXX/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.pyc in __init__(self, input, output, name)
   1599             # check that x is an input tensor
   1600             layer, node_index, tensor_index = x._keras_history
-> 1601             if len(layer.inbound_nodes) > 1 or (layer.inbound_nodes and layer.inbound_nodes[0].inbound_layers):
   1602                 cls_name = self.__class__.__name__
   1603                 warnings.warn(cls_name + ' inputs must come from '

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'inbound_nodes'
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? Facing the same Problem currently.

Comment: This link could be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62092966/how-can-i-obtain-define-input-output-names-of-my-graph-or-freeze-it-in-proper-fo#

Answer (score 6):

As of TensorFlow 2.0 *(unfortunately they seem to change this often)* you can export the model to the `SavedModel` format -in python- using

```py
model.save('MODEL-FOLDER')
```

and then inspect the model using the [saved_model_cli](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#show_command) tool (found inside python folder `<yourenv>/bin/saved_model_cli` -*in anaconda at least*)

```
saved_model_cli show --dir /path/to/model/MODEL-FOLDER/ --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default
```

the output will be something like

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['graph_input'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_DOUBLE
      shape: (-1, 28, 28)
      name: serving_default_graph_input:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['graph_output'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 10)
      name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

By inspecting the output, you can see the name of the input and output tensors in this case to be, respectively: **serving_default_graph_input** and **StatefulPartitionedCall**

This is how you find the tensor names.

*The right way to do this, though*, is to define a graph path and its output and input tensors on the model using [SignatureDefs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/signature_defs). So you's load those **SignaturesDefs** instead of having to deal with the tensor name's directly.

This is a nice reference that explains this better than the official docs, imo:

https://sthalles.github.io/serving_tensorflow_models/

Answer (score 2):

Call a `model.summary()` in Keras to see all the layers.

An input tensor will often be called `input_1`, `input_2`, etc. See in the summary the correct name.

---

When you use `input_shape=(3,15,15)` in Keras, you're actually using tensors that have shape `(None, 3, 15, 15)`. Where None will be replaced by the batch size in training or prediction.

Often, for these unknonw dimensions, you use `-1`, such as in `(-1, 3, 15, 15)`. But I cannot assure you that it will work like this. It works perfectly for reshaping tensors, but for creating I've never tested.

Answer (score 0):

To get the input and output tensors of your Keras models, do the following:

```
input_tensor = seq.inputs[0]
output_tensor = seq.outputs[0]
print("Inputs: "+str(input_tensor))
print("Outputs: "+str(output_tensor))
```

The above assumes that there is only 1 input tensor and 1 output tensor. If you have more, then you would have to use the appropriate index to get those tensors.

Note that there is a difference between layer output shapes and tensor output shapes. The two are usually the same, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling `summary()` on the loaded model object as suggested in one of the answers. But if you couldn't find the input and output names in the model summary, try calling `input_names` and `output_names` on the model object as below :

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("./model/00001")

print(model.input_names)
print(model.output_names)
```

Tried out on TensorFlow version : `2.3.1`